# Change javascript popup window from onclick to onmouover

Tags: javascript

How do I change the following javascript for popup window from "open popup onclick" to open/close popup onmouseover/onmouseout.

```
<area alt="" coords="127, 22, 20" alt="" href="includes/popup1.htm" onclick="javascript:void window.open('includes/popup1.htm','1366002941508','width=500,height=200,left=350,top=250');return false;" shape="circle" />
```

Comment: tried onmouseover=  instead of onclick= ?

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to the popup window when you open it, and call `.close()` on the window in the `mouseout` handler:

```
<area
    onmouseover="popup = open('includes/popup1.htm','1366002941508','width=500,height=200,left=350,top=250');"
    onmouseout="popup && popup.close();"
    coords="127, 22, 20" alt="" href="includes/popup1.htm" shape="circle" />
```

But, now that the popup is not triggered by a click, you'll surely be blocked by popup blockers.  Consider showing the content in a floating div instead of a separate window.

Comment: Gilly3, I guess what I really would like is my code to do is as follows: (1) opening onclick and closing after 5 secs; AND (2) opening/closing on onmouseover/onmouseout. Can you help please.

Comment: @user964377 - Use `setTimeout` to call `window.close()` after 5000 ms.

Comment: Many thanks. Where exactly does the setTimout need to be placed?

Comment: Gilly, the open onClick is opening a standard page not a popup.